# Android Launcher Drag and Drop on 2 pages

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, swipe, launcher, homescreen

I am implementing a customized launcher for my homescreen.
I would like to have the swiping as well as drag and drop feature. 
How could I drag an icon from one page and drop it on the other page? I believe this is possible since I have seen it from most of the launchers but I cannot think of a possible way.

Comment: No. This was no longer needed on our project. You can however use this for drag and drop: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html. I am not sure how to implement it for dragging outside the same screen, though.

Comment: I have drag and drop implemented. Only carrying the view to another page is left.